# Remote Desktop Host Server and Domain Controller on one machine

Tags: remote-desktop-services

According to this guide

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817595(v=ws.10).aspx

RDP host server should NOT be the domain controller.

How then can this be set up using ONE machine? (not including the clients)

I'm new to server stuff and just learning as I go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set them up on the same operating system. You don't want *anyone* to have access to a domain controller other than trusted systems administrators. Ever.

If you really must use a single piece of hardware, what you should do is use some virtualization software to separate the roles into two separate server installs that run simultaneously, but are logically separate. Hyper-V Server or ESXi are the two largest players in the server virtualization market. I'd recommend one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately I really must use a single piece of hardware. How does this relate to the Hyper-V Role that can be installed in Server Manager? And can you point me in the direction of any good guides or somewhere I can start to set up these 2 separate server installs that will run simultaneously using Hyper-V.

Comment: Don't use the hyper-v role. Install hyper-v server and install both OSes as guests. There's plenty if info on technet.microsoft.com

Comment: @Vazgen You seem to be in way over your head.  "How do I use virtualization" is not a good question for this site.  (Or in general, IMO.)